# Passing template parameters to nested structs

Tags: c++, templates, struct, nested

I'm trying to add a nested struct (Node) that takes the same template param 'T' passed into the baseclass (LinkedList).

When I try to template the outer LinkedList class, I get a "explicit specialization of non-template class LinkedList" error. If I don't add it, the private Nodes "head" and "tail" don't recognize 'T'

When I add the template to the Node class, I get a "Declaration of 'T' shadows template parameter" error. However, if I don't add it explicitly to the Node class, the 'T' is not recognized at all in the struct.

How do I declare template and pass it correctly from the LinkedList class to the nested, private Node struct correctly?

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList<T> {

private:
    template<typename T>
    struct Node {
        T value;
        Node<T>* next;
        Node<T>* previous;
        Node<T>(T value, Node<T>* next, Node<T>* previous)
        :value(value),
        next(next),
        previous(previous){}
        Node<T>& operator=(const Node<T>&) = delete;
    };

    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;

    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList&) = delete;

public:
    LinkedList<T>()
        :head(nullptr),
        tail(nullptr){}
    ~LinkedList<T>();
    LinkedList& insertTail(T value);

};
```

Comment: `Node` doesn't not have to be a template. You can (and should) just use `T` from `LinkedList` (which should not have the `<T>` after the name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring a primary template (i.e., not a specialization), don't add `<T>` after the name:

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList {
```

`Node` shouldn't be a template; for any particular `T`, a `LinkedList<T>` should only have one type of `Node`s  - those that hold `T`:

```
struct Node {
    T value;
    Node* next;
    // ...
};
```

Finally, the `<T>` is implied when you write the template's name in its definition, so you don't need to explicitly specify it:

```
LinkedList() 
    :head(nullptr),
    tail(nullptr){}
~LinkedList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Lose all the extraneous `<T>` madness and simply used the outer template parameter. It is perfectly legal to do so:

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node {
        T value;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;

        Node(T value, Node* next, Node* previous)
            : value(value), next(next), previous(previous)
        {}
        Node& operator=(const Node&) = delete;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList&) = delete;

public:
    LinkedList()
        : head(nullptr)
        , tail(nullptr)
    {}
    ~LinkedList();

    LinkedList& insertTail(T value);
};
```

Related: My crystal ball tells me [**you should read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) before implementing the rest of the functions that are only declared here.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question/answer, it was really helpful!